# Virtual machine disk space in Docker for Windows beta

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

In my old docker container, created with the docker toolbox on Windows I was able to use the

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size 50000 default
```

command to create the container with more disk space as I have big images stored in it and/or "create another environment" next to the default.

Since the upgrade to the Docker 1.12.0 beta18 from the old Docker Toolbox I have no idea how to do that and I am facing the "low disk space" problem.

I would like to be able to create the default environment with more disk space available for virtual machine created.

Is there any chance to do that, please? The docker docs does not mention that for the new Windows version.

Comment: This is a little old, but see: https://forums.docker.com/t/consistently-out-of-disk-space-in-docker-beta/9438/18 . You probably will need to use Vagrant to have more control over the disk space. I'm assuming you are using volumes where you can to externalize large files, logs, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

The MobyLinux Hyper-V machine is provisioned on first start of docker on your computer.

There is no way to change the original 60GB size by configuration, how is stated inside the *C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\MobyLinux.ps1* (powershell script):

```
# Hard coded for now
$global:VhdSize = 60*1024*1024*1024  # 60GB
```

So, my "hack" solution was to change this line to

```
$global:VhdSize = 120*1024*1024*1024  # 120GB
```

Pretty lame, but it will work! You need however to reset your docker, causing it to provision again the hyper-v machine.

Answer (score 1):

As an update to this question you can now change the VHD size in the Docker settings (in v18.02 on the edge channel at time of writing). Changing the MobyLinux settings via the powershell script will not work anymore.

See https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1042 (and scroll down) for more information.